# Установка значения по умолчанию для get-запроса

Tags: php, get, фильтр

Друзья помогите пожалуйста!
Есть Форма с методом get, в ней Параметры произвольных полей (cena и cena_2):
min-price, min-price_2, max-price, max-price_2, мне необходимо установить значение по умолчанию (не value в Форме, так не пойдет) которое будет подставляться при условии что поле не было заполнено Пользователем!
Я прописал вот так для min-price и min-price_2:

'

```
    <?php if (isset($_GET['min-price'])){
     $value = $_GET['min-price'];
     } else {
     $value = '0';
    };
          if (isset($_GET['min-price_2'])){
     $value = $_GET['min-price_2'];
     } else {
     $value = '0';
    } ?>
```

'

Сработало, НО:
Во-первых, таким же образом пытался прописать для max-price и max-price_2 - НИ В КАКУЮ!
Во-вторых, заметил что работает только значение "0"...
В-третьих, даже удалив этот код он все равно срабатывает! (чистил браузер, пробовал с других устройств)

Очень прошу помощи, ума не приложу каким образом оно работает даже когда удалил код...
Подскажите в чем дело? Подозреваю что как-то глобально установилось значение "0" но я его прописывал только на странице вывода записей с Формы и нигде больше...

И как прописать в итоге значения по умолчанию для одних параметров 0, а для других 99999 ???

Вывожу данные по такому коду:

'

```
    <?php $args = array( 
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
     'tax_query' => array(  
              array(  
          'taxonomy' => 'category',  
          'field' => 'id',  
          'terms' => array($_GET['category'])  
                   ),
             ),

      'meta_query' => array(  
                     array(  
                    'key' => 'cena',  
                    'value' => array( $_GET['min-price'], $_GET['max-price'] ),
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'  
                        ),  
                     array(  
                    'key' => 'cena_2',  
                    'value' => array( $_GET['min-price_2'], $_GET['max-price_2'] ),
                   'type' => 'numeric',
                   'compare' => 'BETWEEN'  
                        ) 
                      ),
                   );

                    query_posts( $args ); ?>


                     <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

'

Comment: Во-первых, у $_GET['min-price'] и $_GET['min-price_2'] вы записываете в одну переменную - $value, всегда будет браться итог последнего... Во-вторых, проверяйте так: `$minPrice = empty($_GET['min-price']) ? 0 : (int)$_GET['min-price']; $minPrice2 = empty($_GET['min-price_2']) ? 0 : (int)$_GET['min-price_2'];`

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема решена! Затупил под утро)